# Does absolute convergence imply conditional convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

My problem is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} $ absolute converges does it imply that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}^{2} $ converges?

My proof for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} $ absolute converges does it imply that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} $

1. $-|a_{n}| \le a_{n} \le |a_{n}|$
2. $0 \le a_{n} + |a_{n}| \le 2|a_{n}|$
3. If $\sum_{}^{} a_{n}$ converges than $2\sum_{}^{} a_{n}$ converges $\implies$$2\sum_{}^{} |a_{n}|$ converges
4. We have $\sum_{}^{} a_{n} + |a_{n}|$ converges since $\sum_{}^{} 2|a_{n}|$ converges and $a_{n} + |a_{n}| \le 2|a_{n}|$
5. But since $a_{n} \le a_{n} +|a_{n}|$ then $\sum_{}^{} a_{n} \le \sum_{}^{} a_{n}+|a_{n}|$ which converges so $\sum_{}^{} a_{n}$ converges.

Can I use this proof to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} $ absolute converges does it imply that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}^{2} $ converges?
Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: Yes, it's also converge!

Comment: the result is true but these things are not so useful. Hint - for $n$ large, $|a_n|<1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ absolute converges that means $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ |aₙ| converges. Hence, this implies |aₙ|< k some positive real k.
So, now |aₙ²|<k|aₙ| for all n,
So this implies now $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$|aₙ²| convergent, as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ |aₙ| is convergent( by comparison test).
So, that's mean $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ aₙ² is absolutely convergent.